# Tidy HTML formatting in Gutenberg HTML blocks

Tags: html, block-editor

When forming my own HTML within Gutenberg HTML blocks, trying to keep my HTML tidy for easy debugging purposes is a pain because tab indenting cannot be used, and therefore multiples of 4 spaces or more has to be used for each indentation level.  Having to count 1,2,3,4...1,2,3,4...1,2,3,4 for example to keep everything in line slows down page production too.

Is there a way of allowing tab indenting to be used within Gutenberg blocks?

Comment: specifically for the HTML block; or the HTML that is in the code editor?

Comment: @Will I want to be able to tab indent HTML within HTML blocks. I just edited my question in the hope of making it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there's anything available that would allow this unless you do some extensive customization to the [block editor](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor).

TAB is used very often by users who have limited dexterity (I use it myself) so entering TAB on the keyboard will be used to move to the next element on the page.